Is ELK 7.10 started to use account password and certificate to access ELK components?
In ELK 6.5, by using SSL certificate only, we can access different ELK components.
When I tried using ELK 7.10 (X-pack or security stuff), it starts using account, password, and SSL certificate. Is it normal for ELK to have such changes between 6.5 and 7.10? When is the version change started ?
I tried searching on stack overflow, but found no answers.

Starting from version 6.8, Elastic introduced the "free basic security" features, which included basic authentication and security capabilities, such as username/password authentication and SSL/TLS encryption, as part of the free default distribution of the Elastic Stack. Prior to this, securing ELK required additional plugins and purchasing a subscription to X-Pack, which is now known as the Elastic Stack Security.
Currently there are 3 security options.

Set up minimal security
Set up basic security
Set up basic security plus HTTPS

Q: In ELK 6.5, by using SSL certificate only, we can access different ELK components.
A: I assume that in your case user authentication was disabled or maybe anonymous user access enabled. Elasticsearch v7 and onwards, you should provide username and password even for minimal security.
Elasticsearch v6.5 how security works article
